# How to deploy Go apps with internal package to Heroku using `dep`

Tags: go, heroku, dep

I am using Heroku's Golang buildpack to deploy a simple web app with the following structure

```
my-app/
    handler/
        user.go
        session.go
    vendor/
        github.com/
        golang.org/
    main.go
    Gopkg.toml
    Gopkg.lock
```

Inside my main file, I imported my own `handler` package

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "my-app/handler"
)
```

Heroku was not able to run go install on my project due the following error:

```
----> Using go1.9.3
----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku . 
----> cannot find package "my-app/handler" in any of: ...
```

I can run `go install` and `my-app` without any problem locally. It seems to me that heroku does not recognize my internal project package.

I am using dep and I have the following configurations in my Gopkg.toml:

```
[metadata.heroku]
root-package = "github.com/mygithub/my-app"
go-version = "go1.9.3"
install = ["."]
ensure = "false"
```

What else do I need to do to deploy a Go app with internal package? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the root package to just the name of the project without the domain

`[metadata.heroku]
  root-package = "my-app"
  go-version = "go1.9.2"
  install = [ "./..." ]`

Comment: Yep that worked. I actually only changed root-package to "my-app". I didn't need to do install = ["./..."]. Now I am doing it just in case. Just want to say, thank you very much, your help is much appreciated.